# Long transaction in WebSphere 6.1 results in OutOfMemoryException

Tags: hibernate, spring, transactions, websphere, out-of-memory

I’m running a synchronization / batch job (synchronizeXXX() that inserts 111821 records in an Oracle database using **Hibernate 3.2.5GA / Spring 2.5.6** in one long running transaction (>4 hours) but it fails after approx. 2 hours / 50000 records with an OutOfMemory exception.
Although i do **clear and flush** every 20 inserts, it still looks like Hibernate/Websphere/Spring (?) is holding on to a gazillion objects in the session.

The funny thing is:  the memory usage is initially normal, but after approx. 20/30 minutes the memory usage starts to increase and grows until the OutOfMemory occurs (not shown in PDF because it was scrolled out/cleared or something). I tried upgrading Hibernate from 3.2.5 
to 3.3.2GA but the same problem remained.
When I increase the max heap size, the OutOfMemory just comes later.

I googled and found some ‘similar’ issues, but they used Hibernate to manage the transaction instead of Spring, so I guess the fix  mentioned is not relevant to me(?). See [Simular issues](https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=995325)

I analysed the heap dumps and did some analysis with the IBM Support Agent 4.1. All results/screenshots and more details are **included in a PDF**: see [OutOfMemory analysis (PDF 586KB)](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/154204/OutOfMemory_WebSphere_Hibernate.pdf)

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even if you are doing clears and flush from time to time the Hibernate session and transaction is still open and clear doesn't seem to work as it should in your case.

The options here seem to be:

a) Use stateless session: http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/batch.html

b) Use SQL queries so hibernate cannot hold anything

c) Use several transactions

There is no great solution here, so just value the best option for you :(

Comment: Thanks. c) is not an option for us. Can i use a) if i have generated keys (sequence in Oracle)? If so, i have to insert all members/collections myself i think. BTW: we're considering a move to PL/SQL because the performance now is dramatic: since the data (one large XML file) is already *in* the database in a Clob, this should speed things up.

Comment: Never used a stateless session but I understand that you have to insert every element one by one and from children to father so everything ends as it should. Moving everything to PL/SQL can be a solution but maybe using b) allows you to use XML parsing capabilities of Java, should greatly reduce the process times and avoid the cache problem at the same time, just send SQL through Hibernate.

Comment: btw. I used another transactionmanager (some standard HibernateTX manager; i have to look it up) in the spring config, and viola the memory usage was stable for two hours!! After this it times out though, but I guess thats another problem ;-)